# Double for loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a problem with this code:

```
num = 111
num_list = list(map(int, str(num)))
i=len(num_list)
t=2**(i-1)
answer = sum([x*(l**2) for x in reversed(num_list) for l in range(len(num_list))])
if answer % 5 == 0:
  print(answer, "is divisible by 5")
else:
  print(answer, "is not divisible by five")
```

Yes it does work if you test it but it gives me :

```
15 is divisible by 5
```

instead of:

```
7 is not divisible by 5
```

So basically what my code does is it takes a binary number and turns into decimal and tests whether or not the decimal is divisible by 5. Don't ask me how but I know there is some problem with my list comphrehension and my double for loop. Please help and thank you!

Comment: for ```num = 111``` ```answer = sum([x*(l**2) for x in reversed(num_list) for l in range(len(num_list))])``` yields 15 not 7, your conversion of binary to decimal is incorrect/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic for converting binary to decimal is a bit off.
Try this:

```
answer = sum([x*(2**l) for l, x in enumerate(reversed(num_list))])
>>> answer
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this as well:

```
num = 111
num_list = list(map(int, str(num)))
i=len(num_list)
t=2**(i-1)
answer = 0
for l in num_list:
  answer += l*t
  t=int(t/2)
if answer % 5 == 0:
  print(answer, "is divisible by 5")
else:
  print(answer, "is not divisible by five")
```